# How to register event listeners in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

Apologies if this is a very basic question as I have zero knowledge about Web development.

I am trying to test Apple's CloudKit Web services as mentioned in their documentation at
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices.html

To compose Web Service Request, I need `ckWebAuthToken`

Apple Documentation says, to get `ckWebAuthToken` Apple will present an actual Sign in page through a redirect URL, and once the user signs in, the response contains a `ckWebAuthToken`

In particular, the documentation says, register an event listener with the window object to be notified when the user signs in.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data.ckWebAuthToken);
})
```

My question is how do I register the above event listener in browser to fetch `ckWebAuthToken` in the browser console?

Comment: You don't. You just assign that value to a variable (e.g., `const token = e.data.ckWebAuthToken;`) then use it how you see fit (all within the `function (e) { ... }` scope)

Comment: Heretic, I do not have access to the source code of sign in page. The sign in page is from Apple. I just have to sign in and get the ckWebAuthToken.

Comment: You register that event listener on the web page that opens the sign in page on Apple's domain. Apple's page will post a message to its opener with the token. That event listener listens for that message.

Comment: Actually, the source of Sign in is not a Web page, but a native Android Screen with a button. On tap of button, a WebView is displayed that contains Apple's sign in page. Is there a way I just open the Sign in page in browser, sign in and get that ckWebAuthToken in browser's console ?

Comment: You should tag the question appropriately. It seems as though this question is not really about JavaScript in the browser, but about how to get the token for that API using Android. I don't think you want to get your Web Authn token by parsing the console. That would be a waste of resources and very error prone.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Parsing the console is error prone. Thank you for your help.